# How to prove that this binomial sum remains positive for $x>1$?

Tags: polynomials, summation, binomial-coefficients, roots

Let's say you have this function for real numbers $x>1$, for some positive integer $n \geq 1$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor n/2 \right \rfloor} {x \choose 2k+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}}
$$

How would you prove that this function is positive for all $x>1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$? For positive integers, the binomial coefficients are positive for some real number $x>n$, but it's not clear for a real number since the binomial coefficient expanded to the real number field requires the use of the gamma function which changes signs depending on the negative real number. I know that for the case of $n$ odd this polynomial has 1 real root which is $x=0$, and for $n$ even it has roots $x=0,1$ but not sure where to go from here to prove this for all real numbers $x>1$?

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is to try t9 use $$\binom xm =(-1)^m\binom{m-1-x}m.$$ But not sure how.

Comment: The alternative is to prove it for even and odd $n$ seperarely, by induction, proving for $n=0$ and $n=1,$ then proving from $n$ t9 $n+2.$ But again, not sure if that will work.

Comment: You can also write this as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x-1}{k},$$ where $x-1>0$. Not sure if that helps, but this is the unique polynomial of degree $n$ that takes values $y=1,2,\dots,2^n$ on $x=1,2,\dots,n+1$.